# mysql - is it possible to get most recent rows in a database regardless any database column?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there some mechanism in mysql for getting the newest rows in a certain database regardless the table new rows are.

I would like to find out these columns without any help of columns stored in the table (like id, created_at). Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

It is generally a good practice that one maintain a log table for a database regardless of if it is mysql or any other db. Such a log table for a database should capture/store items like

> USER_AGENTS , type of CRUD operations on TABLE, TIMESTAMP...among others

This is very much required so that one can view through the logs during any abnormal activities or downtime.

Coming back to your question, if you have such a log table, you could capture the table name and row id for any table for any such new records so that you can achieve what you want from this log table.
But again, if that is not the case, it should still serve as a point to note while designing new database in the future.

Comment: Thanks, @Capitan Red!  Well I know mysql specifically has the bin logs and I know it would be possible to handle it for getting the information I want. But It can be cumbersome. Can't it? I'm looking forward to find some native feature that might performe such query :)

Comment: @OmarAlves Yes, they do have bin logs but I am afraid if you can query them from within your code. If you do find any method as such, please do post the answer and a tag for me on the comment :) I know maintaining log tables can be cumbersome too but its just a good practice and that you can carry the log codes form project to project.